# Correct incorrect host_1 tag on new measurements in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I have a problem where my new metrics are getting logged on "host_1", with the host tag being empty:

```
select * from telegraf.live.swap where time < '2020-01-25T21:44:00Z' order by time desc limit 10
```

```
name: swap
time                 free       host                 host_1               in         out
----                 ----       ----                 ------               --         ---         
2020-01-25T21:43:50Z 3756060672                      web3 6962348032 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:43:40Z 3756060672                      web3 6962348032 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:43:30Z 3756060672                      web3 6962343936 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:43:20Z 3756060672                      web3 6962343936 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:43:10Z 3756060672                      web3 6962343936 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:43:00Z 3756060672 web3                      6962343936 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:42:50Z 3756060672 web3                      6962343936 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:42:40Z 3756060672 web3                      6962343936 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:42:30Z 3756056576 web3                      6962339840 12493660160
2020-01-25T21:42:20Z 3756056576 web3                      6962339840 12493660160
```

I have tried to backup to swap2, and drop the measurement, after which the metrics correctly get logged with tag host='web3'. However, after doing this:

```
select * into telegraf.live.swap from telegraf.live.swap2 where host='web3' group by *
```

Then I get the same situation, with all the new metrics ending up with host_1 filled, and host empty, while those inserted from swap2 are ok.

Can anyone explain this?
Or any hints how I can resolve this?

Update:
I checked what telegraf is sending to influxdb, and the metrics line looks like this:

```
swap,host=web3 used=345272320i,free=3748364288i,used_percent=8.434366629545249,total=4093636608i 1580589300000000000
```

Update:
Some further checking reveals that on this measurement, there is a tag named host, and also a field named host. New metrics come in on the tag, while my old data has only fields.

Still, my problem remains: how can I merge these two columns into a single "host" tag? I tried a select into.... group by host (omitting the host column), but then, a number of metrics have an empty host tag :(

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be on InfluxDB side but rather in data being pushed to database. Looks like tag `host` is not filled or supplied by your logging client which sends tag `host_1` instead.

Comment: As mentioned, when I drop the measurement entirely, without changing telegraf, the metrics get logged correctly. But when I then copy the old data back in, new data is logged on host_1 again.

Comment: Still the original source of `host_1` tag in db is telegraf as far as I understand. So telegraf is the main suspect.  I'd suggest to add `[[outputs.file]]` section to telegraf config temporarily to see raw line protocol data sent to db. Also check that `host_1` is really **tag** and not **field**. `host_1` being sent by telegraf as field can explain your observations.

Comment: Checked. Output line from telegraf added to original question.

Comment: Having duplicate tag and field names is generally a way to trouble and should be avoided. Your telegraf output looks fine, all you need is to get rid of duplicate `host` field in `swap` measurement. Use `show tag keys` and `show field keys` commands to verify. And you'll probably have to use `"name"::tag` syntax, see details in (Tag and field key with the same name)[https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#tag-and-field-key-with-the-same-name] section in InfluxDB's FAQ.